# Speeding up a numerical constrained quadratic optimization

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve a quadratic optimization problem in 35 variables, $\vec{α} = \left< α_1, \ldots, α_{35}\right>$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname*{maximize}_\vec{α}&&1.0\cdot α_1 - 2.7\cdot {α_1}^2 + 1.0\cdot α_2 + \cdots + 0.6\cdot α_{34} \cdot α_{35} -1.6 \cdot {α_{35}}^2 \\
&\operatorname*{subject to}&&0 = α_1 + α_2 + \cdots - α_{34} + α_{35} \\
&&& \forall_i(α_i \geq 0)
\end{aligned}
$$

where the expression to be maximized has 665 terms, all linear or quadratic.

The obvious command:

```
nn = 35;
objective = 1.0*Subscript[α,1] - 2.7*Subscript[α,1]^2 + [...];
equalityConstraint = 0 == Subscript[α,1] + Subscript[α,2] + [...];
NMaximize[{objective, equalityConstraint} ~Join~ Table[Subscript[α, n] >= 0, {n, 1, nn}],
    Table[Subscript[α, n], {n, 1, nn}]]
```

runs too slowly. I suspect that Mathematica's full nonlinear-optimization machinery, unneeded for this type of problem, may be slowing it down. What can I do to increase performance?

Comment: You will probably be better off using `FindMinimum` with `Method -> "QuadraticProgramming"` or `"LevenbergMarquardt"` rather than `NMinimize`, as the latter uses derivative-free metaheuristic approaches that are not well suited for this problem.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: I thought `FindMinimum` only gives a *local* minimum.

Comment: That's correct, but you can still use it, via the `"RandomSearch"` method of `NMinimize`, if you want to try to find the global minimum. Of course, that you will actually find it can't be guaranteed unless you use `Minimize`, but I expect this will be even slower than `NMinimize`, if it works at all.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: What do you mean by using `FindMinimum` via the `"RandomSearch"` method of `NMinimize`?

Comment: For example, `Method -> {"RandomSearch", Method -> "QuadraticProgramming", "PostProcess" -> "KKT"}`. Unfortunately, although it does as requested, it seems that this does not give very good results, since `NMinimize` first transforms into an unconstrained problem, which `FindMinimum` doesn't particularly like. I don't have time to investigate this now, but in the mean time you could use the BFGS algorithm (`Method -> "QuasiNewton"`) in place of Levenberg-Marquardt/quadratic programming to get around the issue. This seemed to work acceptably well in my brief tests.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: I tried `NMaximize` with `Method->{"RandomSearch",Method->"QuasiNewton","PostProcess"->"KKT"}` on a similar smaller problem (7 vars), but it fails after a long time with `NMaximize::cvmit: "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within \[NoBreak]100\[NoBreak] iterations. "`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail can you give us the objective formulation explicitly in your code. Then one may give the problem a better try.

Comment: Actually `FindMaximum` with `Method->"QuadraticProgramming"` can give the global optimum. If the objective is the negative of a convex function then that should go to a global max. I'm guessing this is the case, since otherwise Levenberg-Marquardt would not be a viable approach (also i believe the quadratic programming method would give a failure message). If the objective is not negative semidefinite then you might still get a reasonable result with `Method->"InteriorPoint"`.

Comment: @OleksandrR's suggestion to use a quadratic programming solution typically requires 0.02 seconds or less when applied to problems of the same size having random coefficients.